# Article: An univesity or A university

Tags: grammar, articles

### U article

*hello guys*

Some days ago, I heard one thing from my teacger, he said an university is wrong and we have to say a university.
He called this knowledge: phonology and phonetic.
Can you explain is it true or not and why?
A university or an university?
A useful or an useful?
A user or an user?
A ugly or an ugly?

---

Thanks❤

Comment: The choice of "a" or "an" is based on how the word is pronounced, not how it's spelled. Since "university" begins with a consonant sound "y", you use "a", not "an".

Comment: This is something English speakers learn as little children. If you're learning English now, you should ask in [ell.se].

Comment: The choice of "a" or "an" is **largely** based on how the word is pronounced. There is at least one grey area (eg aspirated _an hotel_).